# C# Sorting a List of Objects by Name and Coord

Tags: c#, list, sorting

to set the scene, I have a list of objects.
Each object contains a name, and a point consisting of an x coordinate and a y coordinate.

I currently have the list sorted to group up the object's name in alphabetical order. Now I want the same named objects to be ordered by descending or ascending x coordinates.

- What is inside the list now:

  - BP301 (5, 6)
  - BP301 (-3, 2)
  - BP301 (0, 4)
  - BP301 (5, 6)
  - BP302 (10, 7)
  - BP302 (10, 7)
  - GP001 (8, 3)
- What I want inside the list:

  - BP301 (-3, 2)
  - BP301 (0, 4)
  - BP301 (5, 6)
  - BP301 (5, 6)
  - BP302 (10, 7)
  - BP302 (10, 7)
  - GP001 (8, 3)

Hopefully my question is clear enough

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now to store and sort these objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using LINQ?

Rough example given no code, so I'm assuming an `IEnumerable<T>` compatible list:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ThenBy(i => i.X).ThenBy(i => i.Y);
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you. I need to look more into LINQ. I'm bad with list sorting.

Comment: Yeh there's a bunch of fun stuff you can do, sort ascending, sort descending, group and so on.